# A TeX math font for Helvetica Neue?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Somebody insists for using [Helvetica Neue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica#Neue_Helvetica_.281983.29) (Light) in a new (math) journal, though I advise against it, because it doesn't provide math nor small caps support.

Anyway, could you advise as TeX math font that looks as good as possible with this font?

Comment: I would like to see that somebody in person. I'll bring my Arial Black bat in appropriate size :D

Comment: This would be better to ask in the chat room of TeX.SE or of Graphic Design – you really can use any font with TeX, so there's no technical limitation.  That said, I'm wondering whether the 'not ask and say you did' approach will work here :) Personally sounds like an awful choice for body text.

Comment: @SeanAllred Not quite true, hardly all zillions of fonts out there have a full math support.

Comment: @tohecz Whoops, yes – math support is important, but I don't think it's very particular to TeX.  My apologies for that.

Comment: Is that person the owner of the new journal and may dictate the font to be used? If not, the effort required to set-up a non-standard font for a single article to be submitted is futile.

Comment: What about MathTime Pro II fonts? Ok, they aren't sans serif, but I'll give them a chance.

Comment: @AlexG That person is the graphic designer of the new layout of that journal. And the choice of the font is not for a single article only, but for the whole issue, for all the issues!

Comment: @SeanAllred I'm asking here instead on Graphic Design as graphic designers are likely to not be as familiar with math as many contributors of TeX.SE. About chat rooms, I have never used any chat room but if I'm strongly driven there, I'll go! :)

Comment: @Astrinus The graphic designer strongly insists for a sans serif font.

Comment: Ok. J'ai compris.

Comment: TeX Gyre Heros does have small caps…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the new `newtxsf` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}[Scale=0.9]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`0}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`1}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`2}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`3}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`4}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`5}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`6}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`7}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`8}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`9}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text and a formula $a+b=c$ and a display
\[
\log x=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt
\]
that, together with $1234567890$ ends the paper.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AlbertoSantini I'm crying in despair.

Comment: @egreg You're crying in despair, hence your eyes are filled with tears, hence you don't see anything, hence you don't see how awful this is, hence you aren't crying in despair, hence your eyes are not filled with tears, hence you see everything, hence you see how awful this is, hence you're crying in despair,... Argh, you entered an infinite loop! :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé don't worry, egreg isn't looking at the typography and crying, he's looking at that big green dick and chuckling happily

Comment: ha ha. @DavidCarlisle you're the funniest guy here.

Comment: @egreg What about *Light* Helvetica Neue? I mean is it possible to get math characters as light as text ones ? (Maybe this should be asked in a new question...)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé This is all you get; no `light` option for `newtxsf`. Maybe a feature request for Michael Sharpe. Comment: a long text in Helvetica is horrible, one in Helvetica Light is unbearable.