# How can I set normal text and math labels to Helvetica in a diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, fonts

I need to know why the characters in this diagram are not all set in the same font.  I would like all the text to be set in Helvetica as "cm" is.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}




    % \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    % \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
     \pagestyle{empty}
     \newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}





\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}

\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=2mm]}-{|[width=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.0,0.39215686274509803,0.0}
\definecolor{aqaqaq}{rgb}{0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq, dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm](-7.0,-5.0) grid (7.0,0.0);



\draw [color=aqaqaq,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.2, line width=2.1pt,dash pattern=on 12pt off 12pt] (4.0,-2.0)-- (-4.0,-2.0);



\draw[quote] (-4.0,-4.0) --
node[above] {\Large $85$ cm} (4.0,-4.0);


\begin{scriptsize}


%\draw[color=black] (-4,2.0) node {\textbf{\Huge\textbf{$+$}}};
\draw[color=black] (-4,-2.0) node {\textbf{\Huge\textbf{$A$}}};
;
\draw[color=black] (4,-2.0) node {\textbf{\Huge\textbf{$B$}}};









\draw[color=black] (-5.0,-1.6) node {\Large $h_A$};


\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is *charapter*?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, you have set the text font to be helvetica, but all the characters other than cm are in math

Comment: This is because you've set the default font to be Helvetica, and `cm` is set using that font. All the other components are set in math mode, and therefore use the default math font - Computer Modern - which is not Helvetica. Try something like `$85\,\mathrm{cm}$`.

Comment: I would the document all in Helvetica.

Comment: I think the OP means:  why isn't everything in Helvetica?  And the answer (of course) is that the example given only sets the text font to Helvetica and not the maths font.  Perhaps `sansmath` package can help?

Comment: With that package the pdf file is the same one :(

Could you post the code in order to change the document in Helvetica?

Comment: Or this solution:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218697/a-tex-math-font-for-helvetica-neue

Comment: there is an error :(

Answer (score 2):

`sansmath.sty` could help:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=2mm]}-{|[width=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.0,0.39215686274509803,0.0}
\definecolor{aqaqaq}{rgb}{0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569,0.6274509803921569}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
  \sffamily\sansmath
  \draw [color=cqcqcq, dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,
  xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm](-7.0,-5.0) grid (7.0,0.0);

  \draw [color=aqaqaq,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.2, line
  width=2.1pt,dash pattern=on 12pt off 12pt] (4.0,-2.0)-- (-4.0,-2.0);

  \draw[quote] (-4.0,-4.0) -- node[above] {\Large $85$ cm} (4.0,-4.0);

  \scriptsize

  \draw[color=black] (-4,-2.0) node {\textbf{\Huge\textbf{$A$}}};
  \draw[color=black] (4,-2.0) node {\textbf{\Huge\textbf{$B$}}};
  \draw[color=black] (-5.0,-1.6) node {\Large $h_A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]